# PHP no recibe datos enviados por AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Estoy intentando mandar un arreglo de Js a PHP por medio de AJAX, por el lado de JS me dice que se envia OK, pero al querer recibirlo en PHP no me retorna nada.

El var_dump($_POST); me retorna: array(0) { }

y el ajax success me da esta alerta [image: Mensaje alerta Ajax success]

php: raiz/php/agregarorden.php
html: raiz/html/Mesashtml.php

De esta manera lo estoy intentando.

**JS**

```
let arrayname= [];
  let arraycant= [];
  nomconsu.forEach(function(element) {
    let name = element.innerText;
    arrayname.push(name);
  })

  cantidad.forEach(function(element) {
    let can = element.value;
    arraycant.push(can);
  })

  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"Mesashtml.php",
    data:({ arrayname:arrayname, arraycant:arraycant }),
    success:function(r){
      formordendetalle.submit();
      alert(r);
    }
 });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
include 'conexion.php';
foreach ($_POST['arrayname'] as $value) {
    $sql = $ccn -> query("insert into orden (nom) values ($value)");
    
}
//header('location: ../html/Mesashtml.php?ok=3');

?>
```

Comment: El php esta así porque solo estoy probando si me retorna datos

Comment: Tu pregunta es contradictoria. Dices que el `var_dump($_POST)` te manda un array vacío y a la vez que el `alert` de la respuesta te devuelve unos datos que el código PHP que nos muestras no debería devolver, de modo que no entiendo nada. Además, el parámetro `data` de Ajax va sin paréntesis, así: `data:{ arrayname:arrayname, arraycant:arraycant },` Tampoco entiendo qué hace esto en el bloque `sucess` de tu petición Ajax: `formordendetalle.submit();` Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema contando la verdad de las cosas.

Comment: Creo que expliqué mal, el Ajax en js envía a php, la alerta de la imagen es para validar que si envía la petición con datos pero, el php es quien recibe y el var_dump($_POST) es para mostrar lo que recibe y es donde devuelve vacío.

Comment: Sigo sin entender. ¿Qué código es el que genera lo que nos muestras en la imagen? ¿quitaste los paréntesis que tienes en `data`? ¿para qué es `formordendetalle.submit();`?

Comment: La imagen que dice: localhost dice es el success del Ajax del archivo js. Si quite los paréntesis y nada. El submit es solo para mandar un form

Comment: Ya, pero en la pregunta tú dices esto: *El var_dump($_POST); me retorna: array(0) { }*, pero eso no es cierto, el `var_dump($_POST);` lo que te está devolviendo es lo que hay en la captura de pantalla, o sea, los mismos datos que estás enviando al servidor, o sea, lo que pasas en el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax. ¿Tú dónde estás viendo el `array(0) { }`?

Comment: *El submit es solo para mandar un form* Eso no tiene sentido si usas Ajax, porque en ese caso, los datos se mandan en el parámetro `data`. Si tienes datos en un formulario puedes recogerlos en una variable y pasarlos en el parámetro `data`. No tiene sentido hacer una petición Ajax y mandar un form al mismo tiempo o dentro de `success`.

Comment: La captura no pertenece al `var_dump($_POST)` , pertenece al `alert(r)` del Ajax en el archivo js. El `var_dump($_POST)` lo hago en otro archivo, es el que tengo en el `action`  del form al que le hago submit el cuál uso para redirigirme al php dónde hago el `var_dump($_POST)` el submit solo lo hice para ver lo que me retorna el `var_dump($_POST)`, que me retorna vacio

Comment: Es lo que te acabo de decir en un anterior comentario. Si usas Ajax no necesitas enviar el formulario, porque el envío se hace por medio de Ajax. De hecho, Ajax se creó para eso, antes de Ajax se usaban formularios y necesitas recargar la página cuando los datos eran posteados, mientras que Ajax te permite mandar los datos sin necesidad de recargar la página, así que no tiene sentido mandar el formulario. Lo que ves en pantalla son los datos que estás pasando vía Ajax. Prueba a comentar esta línea y te darás cuenta de que esto va a desaparecer: `array(0) { }`

Comment: Ah ok, no sabía eso sobre el ajax, muchísimas gracias por la aclaración, pero el foreach del php me dice que `$_POST['arrayname]` no está definido, no puse ese error porque no sabía lo del Ajax y creí que con el `var_dump($_POST)` podría mostrar el error. Gracias por la paciencia, soy nuevo en esto :(

Comment: Claro, te dice eso porque tú estás posteando datos anidados. Analiza la captura de pantalla, el valor asociado a `arrayname` es a su vez un array. Como quiera esa estructura es muy rara, no se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres mandar. Debes estructurar los datos de una forma coherente, conforme a lo que quieres mandar, para luego leerlos de ese mismo modo en el servidor.

Comment: Para acceder a lo que tienes en `arrayname` tendrías que hacer algo así, según la estructura actual: `var_dump($_POST['arrayname][0]);` y ahí deberías ver `Sushi`. ¿Por qué? Porque así lo estás mandando. Estás anidando a `Sushi`  dentro de otro array, quizá sin necesidad. Deberías simplificar tu forma de recoger los datos en el cliente. Aunque tampoco queda claro qué es lo que quieres mandar, con qué estructura, ni qué quieres hacer con eso en el servidor.

Comment: Lo que intento es mandar los dos dos array por Ajax, que son "el plato de una orden y la cantidad de ese mismo plato que se pidieron", y recibirlo en php para luego insertarlo en una bd. Esos dos array pueden llevar más datos, no solo [sushi, 1] ,pueden ser varios por eso uso el foreach

Comment: Sería más simple crear desde el cliente algo así: `[{"nombre":"Sushi", "cantidad":1}, {"nombre":"Marisco", "cantidad":3}]` en el supuesto caso de querer mandar un conjunto de datos estructurados con una propiedad `nombre` y otra propiedad `cantidad`. En ese caso, tu `$_POST` será un array de objetos que podrás recorrer y extraer sus valores por cada propiedad `nombre` y `cantidad`. Si creas estructuras complejas, la lectura será compleja. Por eso existe JSON y los datos estructurados, para **simplificar**, no para complicar.

Comment: Ya quedo mucho más claro, intentaré eso, muchísimas gracias por tu apoyo y paciencia

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios problemas en tu código quizá debidos al desconocimiento de cómo funciona Ajax. Es más simple de como lo estás haciendo.

Si usas Ajax no necesitas enviar el formulario, porque el envío se hace por medio de Ajax. De hecho, Ajax se creó para eso, antes de Ajax se usaban formularios y necesitabas recargar la página cuando los datos eran posteados, mientras que Ajax te permite mandar los datos sin necesidad de recargar la página, así que no tiene sentido mandar el formulario. Lo que ves en pantalla son los datos que estás pasando vía Ajax. Eso no quita que puedas tomar datos de un formulario para mandarlos por Ajax, pero mandas los datos, no el formulario en sí mismo.

Por otro lado, estás mandando una estructura complicada al servidor, que no te permitirá luego leer los datos con facilidad.

Si quieres mandar un conjunto de datos al servidor, puedes organizarlos de forma estructurada, así la lectura será más simple.

Por ejemplo algo así:

```
[
  {"nombre":"Sushi", "cantidad":1}, 
  {"nombre":"Marisco", "cantidad":3}
]
```

En este ejemplo, cada objeto tiene una propiedad `nombre` y otra propiedad `cantidad`. En ese caso, tu `$_POST` será un array de objetos que podrás recorrer y extraer sus valores por cada propiedad `nombre` y `cantidad`. Si creas estructuras complejas, la lectura será compleja. Por eso existe JSON y los datos estructurados, para **simplificar**, no para complicar.

Veamos cómo aplicar esto en tu Javascript (cabe decir que JS tiene más herramientas y técnicas para simplificar, pero no nos meteremos en esto ahora, además no tengo tu HTML en contexto).

#### JS

Intentaremos estructurar partiendo de lo que tienes, aunque sería mejor repensar quizá tu propio HTML.

```
let arrayname= [];
let arraycant= [];

nomconsu.forEach(function(element) {
  arrayname.push(element.innerText);
})

cantidad.forEach(function(element) {
  arraycant.push(element.value);
})

let mData = [];

/*
   Combinaremos arrayname y arraycant
   para crear un objeto estructurado
   e iremos metiendo cada objeto en mData
*/

arrayname.forEach(function(value, index) {
    mData.push({"nombre": arrayname[index],"cantidad": arraycant[index]});
});


$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"Mesashtml.php",
    data:mData,
    success:function(r){
        alert(r);
    }
});
```

Aquí estamos en `mData` una estructura parecida a la mencionada más arriba. Ahora en PHP podremos leerla o usarla con más facilidad.

#### PHP

```
var_dump($_POST);
include 'conexion.php';
foreach ($_POST as $value) {
    $sql = $ccn -> query("insert into orden (nom) values ($value['nombre'])");        
}
```

Si quisieras usar `nombre` y `cantidad`, sería algo así:

```
foreach ($_POST as $value) {
    printf("%s%s\n",$value['nombre'],$value['cantidad']);        
}
```